# How to get values from db having null as well as values in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with field update_ version which can have null and some value..

```
Select * from Employee where employee_id =  '1234' and updated_version is null

Select * from Employee where employee_id =  '1234' and updated_version ='1'
```

I have to combine both the queries

I have tried like this but didn't work.

```
Select * from Employee 
where employee_id =  '1234' 
and updated_version = (select case when updated_version is null 
                              then NULL 
                              else updated_version 
                              end)
```

Note: I wil get inputs for employee id and updated_version from other table

Sorry for the Confusion. The updated Version value is not only 1 and null. It can be any value which i'll get from another table. So what ever value i'm getting from other table, I have to query with that condition in Employee table, to get the appropriate result. Not all the result.

Comment: Did you try what Parado said ?

Comment: Show your output table structure.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, a bit unclear as to what you want in the output, but if I get you correctly, you want the rows that have an "updated_version" populated over rows with NULLs for "updated_version"?  Meaning, you want the most "recent" updated version? (assuming there will be many versions/rows in the table for a given employee_id).

Try (untested):

```
select * from (
  select e.*, row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by updated_version desc nulls last) rnum
  from employee e
  where employee_id = '1234'
)
where rnum = 1;
```

The partition by isn't strictly needed as you're looking for just 1 employee_id, but will be needed if you want to expand this to multiple employee ids.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
Select * from Employee 
where employee_id =  '1234' 
and (updated_version is null or updated_version='1')
```

---

EDIT:

```
Select * 
from Employee e
left join other_table ot on ot.employee_id = e.employee_id
                         and ot.updated_version =e.updated_version
```

Comment: If i have to pull updated_version = '1' , I will get both the records having null as well as version with 1. I should get only 1 record having version as 1 :(

Comment: The value will be coming from other table. If an employee having more than one updated_version, we will get last version. If not we will receive it as null

Comment: @muthukumar Try new solution I've added please

Comment: That didn't work either. As the value will be null, we cannot search with = null..

Comment: @muthukumar Can you show as sample data and expected result or if you can [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would the best option

Comment: I have to create one. I have added comments above to make better understanding.. Please let me know if it is not clear..

Comment: @muthukumar Description maybe is good, but better way to understand problem would be provide sample data from both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query out:

```
Select * from Employee where employee_id = '1234' and (updated_version ='1' OR updated_version is null)
```

EDIT: Try this (Untested)!

```
Select * from Employee where employee_id = '1234' and 
CASE updated_version
WHEN '1' THEN '1' 
WHEN Null THEN Null 
ELSE updated_Version
END
```

Comment: As i said, it will return 2 rows if the udpated_version is 1. I should get only one row with version = 1.

Comment: Yeah put everything you'd expect to use in the end in your original question. Also, try the new query.

Comment: I have tried the new query.. Remember the order version is not necessarily 1.. Its just the sample data.. 

I have to query the Employee table for a particular Employee_id and updated_version. I 'll receive the value from the other table. What ever value i received it, When i query in Employee table, I should get rows only for that particular condition.